# Need help importing large company file into QuickBooks Online

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, data-import

I have an existing QuickBooks Enterprise company file that is around 800MB, and I am trying to import all of my data (lists, transactions, etc.) into a new QuickBooks Online account.  None of the suggestions given to me by Intuit have worked, they tell me that I need to reduce my file size to under 250MB before I will be able to import, and none of the options they have given me have gotten my file anywhere close to that size.  Does anyone have any experience doing this, or know of third party software that might do the trick?

Comment: You need to contact Intuit QuickBooks Online support about this.

Comment: I have spoken with them for at least 4 hours.  Well, to be fair at least half of that time was spent on hold.  But they have had no answers for me, everyone I spoke with told me to talk to a different department until I ended up making the rounds to every department at least twice.